# I followed instructions to install Spotify on Ubuntu 13.04 and nothing happened

Tags: installation, spotify

I ran the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client-qt
```

There was no feedback of any kind.  Just the cursor returned.  When I go to look for the application it is not there.  Since other users report success I am hoping there is something elementary that I am missing.

Answer (score 8):

Try the official package, its been a while since they released a preview client for linux.

Basic instructions:

- Add the repo

`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free'`

- Accept spotify server key

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59`

- Update repos and install spotify

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

More details here in the link below:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-install-spotify-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10

Comment: Thanks.  I was forgetting to update the repository.  It all installed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi This worked for me pretty good.!

Add & Update the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the app

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client-qt
```